# How to sign an ActiveXObject code which is implemented in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, code-signing, activexobject

I have this requirement where I need to fetch machine name from user running the application, using ActiveXObject, I am able to get the machine name for my client machine, but as I have to host this on server, IE is giving the following error message-

> Automation Server can't create object.

We cannot reduce the IE security settings in our organisation. So to allow in IE, we need signed ActiveX code, I have the certificate, but I am not sure how to apply that certificate to our ActiveXObject code.
PS:The ActiveXObject code is written in come "*.js" file.

Comment: Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686040/ie9-automation-server-cant-create-object-error-while-using-certenroll-dll), [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814233/how-can-i-sign-an-activex-control-with-a-code-signing-certificate-and-be-a-verif) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041602/how-to-sign-activex-object-in-javascript), then try to enable the "Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting" option and add the url to the "Trusted Sites" area.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tweak Internet Options settings, as it is restricted in the organisation.
Apart from adding it to trusted sites and changing the security settings, is there any other solution or getting the computer name in some other way, using javascript.